# How to extract file name from vsftpd log with shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, vsftpd

I am using vsftpd and I want to extract the file name from successful uploads.
Log example:

```
Tue Feb  6 11:49:25 2018 [pid 13018] [xyz] OK UPLOAD: Client "1.2.3.4", "/filename.zip", 131072000 bytes, 19607.40Kbyte/sec
Tue Feb  6 11:49:25 2018 [pid 13017] [xyz] OK UPLOAD: Client "1.2.3.4", "/filename.zip", 131072000 bytes, 24426.38Kbyte/sec
Tue Feb  6 11:49:30 2018 [pid 13018] [xyz] OK UPLOAD: Client "1.2.3.4", "/filename.zip", 131072000 bytes, 25387.19Kbyte/sec
```

I am using this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

tail -F /var/log/vsftpd.log | while read line; do
  if echo "$line" | grep -q 'OK UPLOAD:'; then
    line=$(echo "$line" | tr -s " ")
    filename=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2)
    echo "$filename"
  fi
done
```

The problem is if the file name has a comma inside, it will not work properly.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `bash` commands for this, better to use this `gnu awk` solution with a `FPAT`:

```
tail /var/log/vsftpd.log |
awk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]*\\]|"[^"]*"' '/OK UPLOAD/{gsub(/[][]/, "", $2);
gsub(/"/, "", $4); cmd=sprintf("echo php /path/to/my/script.php \"%s\" \"%s\"", $2, $4);
cmd | getline result; close(cmd); print result}'

php /path/to/my/script.php xyz /filename.zip
php /path/to/my/script.php xyz /filename.zip
php /path/to/my/script.php xyz /filename.zip
```

Once you are satisfied with the output then remove `echo` before `php`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Inside the loop instead of `echo` I run a php script and pass 2 variables, filename and folder (folder in this case=xyz) can you update your answer to make it work like that? My folder var assignment looks like this: `folder=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f8)` , then I do: `php /path/to/my/script.php "$folder" "$filename"`

Comment: Yes, and run a php script for each line, with those variables passed.

Comment: It's working with commas, but if the file has the sign `&` it will stop the string. For instance, the file name "Test & Test.zip" will result "Test "

Comment: awk: cmd. line:3: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: expression for `|' redirection has null string value

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Hey, for some reason the following line resulted `Feb` and `16:37:55` as parameters: `Wed Feb  7 16:44:15 2018 [pid 21777] [0SZZeYbW] OK UPLOAD: Client "1.2.3.4", "/new-upload-test.txt", 4 bytes, 0.01Kbyte/sec
`

And in another server, almost the exact same line did work as expected:

`Wed Feb  7 16:59:21 2018 [pid 9450] [0SZZeYbW] OK UPLOAD: Client "1.2.3.4", "/new-upload-test.txt", 4 bytes, 0.01Kbyte/sec`

I see that the PID number lengths are different, does it matter?

Comment: As I mentioned in answer, this requires `gnu awk`. Make sure you have `gnu awk` there